# Manipulating arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to C++ and was wondering how best to reorganise data from one array, and put it in another.

Lets say we have a an array that looks like the following, where column A are numbers between 1-5, and B are random integers.

```
A    B
5    12
1    11
2    7
2    3
3    1
5    20
4    4
3    18
```

How would we manipulate the data, such that it summed over repeated numbers in column A, knowing that {1,2,3,4,5} will all appear at least once in column A.

i.e. Would look like

```
A    B(aggregate)
1    11
2    10
3    19
4    4
5    32
```

I assume the code would look something like:

```
double P[7][2]=  {//first table above}
double Q[5][2]= {0};
    for(i=0; i<7; i++){           
        for(j=0;j<5;j++){      
            if P[i][1] = j{   
                Q[j][2]=+P[i][3];  //is this how you add an element 
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Important note before you go much further: Remember that array indices are origin zero. The first element is at `array[0]`, not `array[1]`. You seem to have forgotten this part way through. If the array is size 2, you can only read `array[0]`and  `array[1]`. `array[2]` will compile and sometimes might even look like it produces the correct result, but it is wrong and sooner or later stepping outside the bounds of the array will get you.

Comment: You assume the code would look like that. So did you try that code? What went wrong? What output did you get? Try dealing with one error at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve the desired result by using a `map<int, int>` container, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

map<int, int> m;
vector<int> A = { 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3 };
vector<int> B = { 12, 11, 7, 3, 1, 20, 4, 18 };

int main()
{
    if (A.size() != B.size()) return 1; //error

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) m[A[i]] += B[i];

    // print results
    for (const auto &p : m)
        cout << "m[" << p.first << "] = " << p.second << '\n';
}
```

More info at: [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)